# wrong value for getX() & getY() when rotate view by pinch not activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

Here is what I'm trying to do.
I have a **camera view** user can perform some process (**scale**, **move**, and **rotate**)

I need when user **capture** an image put it in the same location of the camera box with the applied process on a camera view


I'm doing it as follows

**`mCameraView`** is the cameraview and **`mCaptureImage`** is preview image

```
    float x = mCameraView.getX();
    float y = mCameraView.getY();

    mCaptureImage.setX(x);
    mCaptureImage.setY(y);

    float angel = mCameraView.getRotation();
    mCaptureImage.setRotation(angel);

    float scaleX, scaleY;
    scaleX = mCameraView.getScaleX();
    scaleY = mCameraView.getScaleY();

    mCaptureImage.setScaleX(scaleX);
    mCaptureImage.setScaleY(scaleY);
```

and everything is ok if user not rotates the box
but, if user rotated the box I get wrong value for x,y I don't know why this happens and an image is jumped to unspecified location 

I did debug and found that x,y values changed when rotating the view

this is code for **XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/selfie_move_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/selfie_camera_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:cameraCropOutput="true"
    app:cameraPlaySounds="false" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selfie_capture_image"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[Exmaple about rotation view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ImyR.png) 
 
Can anyone help me please t solve this?

Comment: have you understood the question? the rotation for the view not for activity

Comment: did u find solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately, no :(

Answer (score 0):

A rotation of the screen would constitute a configuration change that will change "the current available screen size". To avoid this you must handle the configuration changes yourself using the `configChanges` attribute and specify a value.

It sounds like you should be using the "screenSize" and "orientation" values. This will cause your activity to get a call to `onConfigurationChanged()` rather than recreating the Activity.

> Caution: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.

More information on handling Configuration Changes: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

More on `configChange` attributes: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config

Comment: thanks you for your comment and time but that is not what I'm asking about I'll attach image example